# Stuck with Disassembly

Tags: c, reverse-engineering, disassembly

Need some help with one function, I think it's not hard, could someone translate this to C so I can pick up the logic from there?

```
0x004011cf mov al, byte [esi]

| : 0x004011d1 and eax, 0xff

| : 0x004011d6 mul ebx

| : 0x004011d8 inc esi

| : 0x004011d9 add edi, eax

| : 0x004011db inc ebx

| : 0x004011dc dec ecx

| `=< 0x004011dd jne 0x4011cf
```

Answer (score 6):

Here you go:

`esi` is obviously the pointer to some buffer of length `ecx`

```
LOOP:
      mov al, byte [esi]    ; read byte from memory pointed by esi into low bits of eax
      and eax, 0xff         ; mask eax with 0xff
      mul ebx               ; multiply eax with ebx (wherever ebx came from...)
                            ; put result in eax
      inc esi               ; increment buffer pointer
      add edi, eax          ; add eax to edi (whereever edi came from)
      inc ebx               ; increment ebx
      dec ecx               ; decrement ecx (which is probably some counter)
      jne LOOP              ; jump to LOOP if ecx is different from 0
```

But without any context information it's very hard to tell what this code is actually doing.

The equivalent C code roughly does this:

```
  char *esi;    // points to some buffer...
  int ebx;      // contains some value
  int edi;      // contains some value
  int ecx;      // some counter, presubably the length of the buffer pointed by esi
  ...
  do
  {  
    edi += *esi++ * ebx++;
  } while (--ecx != 0)
```

You need to learn the basics of x86 assembly.